# How to remove particular coupon code if other cart rule without specific coupon is applied on product in magento2?

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart, discount, coupon-codes

**condition 1:** I have 2 cart rule which are directly applied on product if specific conditions are true as given in cart rule.

**condition 2:** there is an another cart rule in which i have added one coupon code "10OFF" for all products.

Question is that if for particular product one cart rule is already applied then i want to remove coupon code 
because same time two discount is applied based on **condition 1** and **condition 2** ,

so how can i remove coupon code if there is already discount is applied by other cart rule ,
please any one have an idea about this let me know. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Check the *priority* value of the rules - the lower the value the higher the priority. Make sure all rules which will be overridden are set to a higher value than your top priority rule.

Then, on the top priority rule, under 'Actions' set 'Discard subsequent rules' to 'Yes', which will stop the lower priority rules from being applied after it.

Comment: this is working but after added one product into cart when i m again adding product into cart then both rule are applied even after applying priority

Comment: Even after applying 'discard subsequent rules'?